# Error cannot implicity convert string[] to char[] for cases

Tags: c#

```
char a = Convert.ToChar("==");
case "==":
if(b==c)
{
    Console.WriteLine("the answer is valid" + b + " " + c);
}
```

I want to know why "Cases" only support character value with single quotations. Why not a string value? Where as in variable a I have stored a string value.

Comment: Are you `switch`ing over `a`?

Comment: Your C# code is invalid. Please post your actual code.

Comment: It depends on the type in the switch() statement.  If you converted to a character then the case is a character.  If the type is a string then the case is a string.

Comment: `case` supports `string` but it depends on input type....

Comment: Switch statements can be goverend by strings: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664749(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple errors or misunderstandings.

---

First, the C# language works as follows:

> - A `String` can be 0 or more characters, and is delimited by `"` (double quotes).
> - A `Char` is exactly 1 character, delimited by `'` (single quotes).

---

Furthermore, the statement **`char a = Convert.ToChar("==")`** will fail because when given a string, it only accepts strings of length 1. And `"=="` has length 2.

To get a single character, use this: **`char a = '=';`**.
Or if you get the string from elsewhere, use **`char a = str[0];`**

---

Finally, the **`switch ... case`** statement can use strings or chars (and also other types, e.g. ints or enums), but *not mixed together*.

So the *type used after* **`switch`** must be the same as the *type used after each* **`case`**.

If the *type used after* **`switch`** is `char`, then the constants after each **`case`** must also be chars, delimited by `'` (single quotes).